My chatting App won't show the messages on the emulator but will process through firebase database. There are no errors but this is a big problem
import 'package:chatting_app/components/chat_bubble.dart';
import 'package:chatting_app/components/my_textfield.dart';
import 'package:chatting_app/services/auth/auth_service.dart';
import 'package:chatting_app/services/chat/chat_service.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


class ChatPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String receiverEmail;
  final String receiverID;

   const ChatPage({super.key,
     required this.receiverEmail,
     required this.receiverID,
  });

  @override
  State<ChatPage> createState() => _ChatPageState();
}

class _ChatPageState extends State<ChatPage> {
  // text controller
  final TextEditingController _messageController = TextEditingController();

  // chat % auth services
  final ChatService _chatService = ChatService();
  final AuthService _authService = AuthService();

  // for textfield focus

  FocusNode myFocusNode = FocusNode();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    // add listener to focus mode
    myFocusNode.addListener(() {
      if(myFocusNode.hasFocus) {
        // cause a delay so that the keyboard has time to show up
        // then the amount of remaining space will be calculated,
        // then scroll down
        Future.delayed(
          const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
            () => scrollDown(),
        );
      }
    });

    // wait a bit for listview to be built, then scroll to bottom
    Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
    () => scrollDown(),
    );
  }
 @override
  void dispose() {
    myFocusNode.dispose();
    _messageController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
  // scroll controller
  final ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();
  void scrollDown() {
  _scrollController.animateTo(_scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent,
      duration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
      curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn
  );
  }

  // send message
  void sendMessage() async {
    // if there is something inside the textfield
    if (_messageController.text.isNotEmpty) {
      // send the message
      await _chatService.sendMessage(
          widget.receiverID, _messageController.text);

      // clear text controller
      _messageController.clear();
    }
    scrollDown();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.background,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.receiverEmail),
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        foregroundColor: Colors.grey,
        elevation: 0,
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          // display all messages
          Expanded(child: _buildMessageList(),
          ),
          // user input
          _buildUserInput(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  // build message list
Widget _buildMessageList() {
    String senderID = _authService.getCurrentUser()!.uid;
    return StreamBuilder(
        stream: _chatService.getMessages(widget.receiverID ,senderID),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
        // errors
          if(snapshot.hasError) {
            return const Text("Error");
          }
        // loading
          if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return const Text("loading..");
          }

        // return list view
          return ListView(
            controller: _scrollController,
            children: snapshot.data!.docs.map((doc) => _buildMessageItem(doc)).toList(),
          );
        },
    );
}

// build message item
Widget _buildMessageItem(DocumentSnapshot doc) {
    Map<String , dynamic> data = doc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;

    // is current user
    bool isCurrentUser = data['senderID'] == _authService.getCurrentUser()!.uid;

    // align message to the right if sender is the current user, otherwise left
    var alignment = isCurrentUser ? Alignment.centerRight : Alignment.centerLeft;

  return Container (
    alignment: alignment,
    child: Column(
      crossAxisAlignment:
      isCurrentUser ? CrossAxisAlignment.end : CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        ChatBubble(
          message: data["message"],
          isCurrentUser: isCurrentUser,
        )
      ],
    ) ,
  );

}

// build message input
Widget _buildUserInput () {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 50.0),
      child: Row(
      children: [
        // textfield should take up most of the space
        Expanded(child: MyTextField(
          controller: _messageController,
          hintText: "Type a Message",
          obscureText: false,
          focusNode: myFocusNode,
        ),
        ),
        // send button
        Container(
          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.green,
            shape: BoxShape.circle,
          ),
          margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 25),
          child: IconButton(
            onPressed: sendMessage,
            icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_upward,
            color: Colors.white,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
}
}


There is no errors in the code messages just won't show up when pressing send. This is the chatting page and I am trying to show the messages between two users within the chatting app but after pressing send the message will not show up but it will process through firebase database so I know there are no problems there but somewhere in this code there is.

I see no calls to the Firestore API in the code you shared, so it's hard to say where the problem comes from. Instead of adding more code from other classes, I recommend studying how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example and creating a new minimal repro from scratch (as explained there).
